# Rally API can't change the Workspace Permission for a user

Tags: node.js, rest, rally

I'm trying to update the "WorkspacePermission" field of a rally user using the rally api. What I'm doing to update the user is:

```
restApi.update({
    ref: '/User/44008770477',
    data: {
        WorkspacePermission: "Workspace Admin"
    },
    fetch: ['WorkspacePermission']}, function(error, data) {
    if(error) {
        console.log(error);
    } else {
        console.log('Updated With Success! ', data);
    } });
```

The request finishes with success but I get a warning "  Warnings: [ 'Ignored JSON element User.WorkspacePermission during processing of this request.' ]".

I don't know why I'm getting this because when I query for the user "44008770477" I get the "WorkspacePermission" field and can see it set to "Workspace User".

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

WorkspacePermission and ProjectPermission objects are generally not updatable.  In this case just delete the existing WorkspacePermission and create a new one for that user.